# Error while performing WFS Update Geometry in demo request under geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I was trying to perform WFS Transaction Update Geom from demo request section under geoserver.
But it is throwing error as Service WFS is disabled. Though I have already enabled it for all the workspaces but then also it is saying same.

Comment: the demos will use the global WFS endpoint not the workspace ones by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have enabled WFS Service for entire geoserver and that helped me to fix the issue